# To what is $V-E+F$ transformed to when $n>3$?

Tags: polyhedra, invariance

I guess that convex polyhedra can be well-defined in $\mathbb R^n$ when $n>3$ and that they are well-studied so would like to know to what does the expression $V-E+F$ transforms to when $n>3$ and is its value known for every $n \geq 3$?

By known, I mean is there some closed-form sequence $n \to w_n$ such that $w_n$ is invariant in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Look up "Euler characteristic" of a "CW complex" or of a "simplicial complex".

Comment: Like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) if you get past the lower dimension content.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_k$ be the count of $k$-dimensional faces of a convex $n$-dimensional polytope. Use furthermore $F_{-1}=F_n=1$ in addition. Then you would simply get the generalized Euler relation
$$0=\sum_{k=-1}^n (-1)^k\ F_k$$
--- rk